# How to write a valid xsd for elements with the same name, but with different content

Tags: xml, xsd

We're having some issues writing the correct (valid) xsd:
- the xsd should validate on http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv
- it should be possible to add the schema to an sql server schema collection (CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION test AS '[xsd here]'
- we need the 'title' attribute values to be specified in the xsd

This is (a drastically simplified) XML structure:

1) This was our first version (which obviously is not valid): You cannot have 2 elements with name 'input' which *are different*.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:element name="test">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="input">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="title" fixed="Pretty title" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="input">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="title" fixed="Different title" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

2) second attempt:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:element name="test" type="Test"/>
<xsd:complexType name="input1">
    <xsd:attribute name="title" fixed="Pretty title" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="input2">
    <xsd:attribute name="title" fixed="Different title" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="input" type="input1"/>
        <xsd:element name="input" type="input2"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

- w3.org comes up with the same error message as before: illegal redeclaration of {None}:input
- xmlspy tells us it's a valid xsd
- sql server throws an error: The content model of type 'Test' contains two elements with the same name 'input' and different types, nillability, or value constraints.

It would be great if someone can give us some insight on this.

Manu.

ps: In reality, our XML structures are way more complex then the example. We're building a web form generator.
Here's another (still simple) example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZForm title="main title" attachment="attachment1" type="NM08">
<Part title="part title">
    <SubTitle code="I.1)" title="title 1"/>
    <ShortText title="short text title 1"/>
    <SubTitle code="I.2)" title="title 2" subtitle="subtitle 1"/>
    <SelectList type="select type" title="select title"/>
    <ShortText title="short text title 2"/>
    <MultiSelectList type="multiType2" title="multi select title"/>     
    <RadioButtonList type="yesNo" title="lala"/>
    <SubTitle code="I.3)" title="some other title" subtitle="what?"/>
    <MultiSelectList type="multiType2" title=""/>
</Part>
<Part title="second part title">
    <Repeater add="add a new repeater item" remove="remove last repeating part">
        <RepeatingPart>
            <SubTitle code="II.1)" title="tiiiiiitle"/>
            <ShortText/>
        </RepeatingPart>
    </Repeater>
</Part>
</ZForm>
```

Comment: Have you tried using attribute groups? What exactly is your requirement for having multiple declarations of `input`?

Comment: As far as I understand, we can not use an attribute group, since the 'fixed' attribute is different in both cases.
And exactly this is why the's the _requirement_ of declaring 2 different input elements..

Comment: So you can use two attribute groups but in your definition for `input` type just specify that either of the groups can be used but not both at the same time. I'm not sure of the syntax off the top of my head but I think it's possible.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSD specification defines a constraint "Element Declarations Consistent" whose effect is that when two sibling elements have the same name, they must also have the same type.

XMLSpy is well known for not enforcing some of the more awkward rules in the spec. I don't know whether it's because they didn't get around to writing the code, or whether they felt that their version was an improvement, but it's always a good idea to check your schema using a tool whose approach to conformance is a bit more rigorous (Xerces is actually stronger on this than the W3C MSV service).

Comment: Does this mean that we can not write a 'strict' schema definition for the xml structure I pasted at the end?
What about xsd 1.1? Would that offer us enough freedom to do that?